# Regular expression for strict decimal numbers

Tags: regex

I want to have a regexp to validate DECIMAL numbers:

The valid DECIMAL numbers are :

```
+123
123
-123
+123.0000
+123,123.999
.0234
+1123,233,34
```

invalid DECIMAL numbers are :

```
+1233+
-1233_
+12.233.33
```

Is there any one who can help on this

Comment: note that these are strict US-en decimal numbers (except for the 7th, do you mean +1123,233.34 ?), they are not all appropriate in Europe.  European countries often use , for the decimal, and . for the separator, for example +123.123,999

Comment: i know this is a regex question, but many languages have parsing routines that are also locale aware, have you considered using one of those? for example, in .NET, Int64.TryParse(...)

Answer (score 2):

This is better:

```
^[+\-]?\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?$
```

Plus or minus, optionally, followed by any number of digits, followed optionally by any number of `,123` sections, followed optionally by a decimal and some more digits, this will handle anything except numbers with a leading decimal.

```
^[+\-]?(\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)$
```

Adding that other option allows numbers with a leading decimal, which MUST be followed by digits.

Comment: Well that's easy to fix, change the `{3}` to a `+`.

Answer (score 1):

This works for all:

```
+123
123
-123
+123.0000
+123,123.999
.0234
+1123,233,34
```

check the demo:

```
^[+\-]?(\d+(,?\d)*(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)$
```

**[Regex Demo](http://regexr.com?32bff)**

Comment: No: You do not need to escape `+` in the character class, the random `+` after all your question marks are meaningless, `[\.]` is unnecessary, the `{1}` after it is even less necessary, and why are you only allowing up to two digits after the decimal? And why is there a plus at the end of your match?

Comment: No: this edit is wrong again. You're allowing multiple decimal point.

Comment: Everything is fixed now..@dan1111

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your regular expression support.

```
^([-+])?(\d+)?(\.\d+)?$
```

Optional + or -, numeric, optional ',' followed by more numerics.
Will also match the empty string unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is about the simplest you can get:

`^[+-]?\d*\.?\d+$`

Digits are always required after the decimal point.  Taking advantage of this fact simplifies the problem.

**Update:** At first I didn't notice that you also need to handle commas.  Here is a simple version that allows commas to the left of the decimal point.  Each comma must have at least one digit before and after it, but other than that no rule is enforced (which seems to be the point of your example data). *Actually, it requires two digits after the final comma.*

`^[+-]?(\d+(,\d)?)*\.?\d+$`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
^([-+] ?)?[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?$
```